# $\sin(na)$ behavior

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry

I am new to real analysis and recently when I am reading about how $\sin(na)$ diverges as $n\rightarrow\infty$. There is a statement that I can't comprehend.

$\forall a\in (0,\pi)\exists n_k\in Z\rightarrow 2k\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{a}{2}\leq n_ka\leq 2\pi k+\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{a}{2}$

Is it possible to prove it as well as providing the intuition about it? I find it abstract especially when another sequence is involved.

Comment: What exactly is it that you do not comprehend about the statement?

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2217717/81360) and [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1816298/81360) are relevant

Comment: In other words, are you trying to understand what the statement says or are you trying to prove the statement?

Comment: Ideally I would like to achieve both but intuition is preferred.

Comment: Fine, but do you understand what the statement says or do you not?

Comment: Partially, so when a is scaled up, it is within something. I understand $\exists k$ s.t. the range starts at $2k\pi$. But starting from $\frac{a}{2}$ and $\frac{pi}{2}$ as well as how $k$ hints to $n_k$ confuse me.

Comment: I would prefer "oscillating between $-1$ and $1$" instead of "diverging". The statement states that , given a fixed arbitary small positive distance, we can find infinite many $n$ such that $na$ is within this distance to some point with $\sin(x)=1$ (and analogue to some point with $\sin(x)=-1$). This implies that the sequence won't converge.